# Elasticsearch template in Logstash doesn't mapping and not able to sort fields

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I want to sort datas via elasticsearch rest client, below is my template in logstash

```
{
  "index_patterns": ["index_name"],
  "template": {
    "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1,
      "number_of_replicas": 0
    },
    "mappings": {
      "_doc": {
          "properties": {
              "int_var": {
                  "type": "keyword"
              }
          }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I try to reach, with the below code

```
{
        "size": 100,
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": {
                    "match": {
                        "match_field": user_request
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "sort": [
            {"int_var": {"order": "asc"}}
        ]
    }
```

I've got this error

```
Text fields are not optimised for operations that require per-document field data like aggregations and sorting, so these operations are disabled by default. Please use a keyword field instead. Alternatively, set fielddata=true
```

How can i solve this ? Thanks for answering

Answer (score 0):

[Here's the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.10/text.html#fielddata-mapping-param) regarding field data and how to enable it as long as you are aware of the performance impacts.

When ingested into Elasticsearch, field values are tokenized based on their data type.
Text fields are broken into tokens delimited by whitespace.  I.E. "quick brown fox" creates three tokens: 'quick', 'brown', and 'fox'.  If you perform a search for any of these three words, you will generate matches.
Keyword fields, on the other hand, create a single token of the entire value. I.E. "quick brown fox" is a single token, 'quick brown fox'.  Searching for anything that is not exactly 'quick brown fox' will generate no matches.

Unless you scrubbed your query before you posted it here, you need to modify the field name under match to be the actual field name, like below.

```
{
        "size": 100,
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": {
                    "match": {
                        "int_var": "whatever value you are searching for"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "sort": [
            {"int_var": {"order": "asc"}}
        ]
    }
```

Comment: I want to get data that match with the name  "match_field", after this match sort via "int_var". I ve asked that how can i do that.  I don't want to match with int_var.